# Double-buffering AlphaBlend rect with text overlay

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm a little confused on how to double buffer this. I'm
not sure if I need to create another `CreateCompatibleBitmap` or `CreateCompatibleDC` and how to link it all.
This works as is but I don't think its double buffered right.

```
void __OnPaint(HWND hWnd, HDC _hdc = nullptr)
{
    HDC hdc = _hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT paint;
    RECT& rcClient = paint.rcPaint;

    if (!_hdc)
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &paint);
    else
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);

    if (hdc)
    {
        int width = rcClient.right - rcClient.left;
        int height = rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top;

        HDC hDCMem = CreateCompatibleDC(_hdc);
        HBITMAP hBitmapMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDCMem, width, height);

        SelectObject(hDCMem, hBitmapMem);

        Rectangle(hDCMem, 0, 0, width, height);

        BLENDFUNCTION bfn;

        bfn.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
        bfn.BlendFlags = 0;
        bfn.AlphaFormat = 0;
        bfn.SourceConstantAlpha = 0x50;

        AlphaBlend(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, hDCMem, 0, 0, width, height, bfn);

        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        DrawText(hdc, "Your text here", -1, &rcClient, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);

        //BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, hDCMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        DeleteDC(hDCMem);
        DeleteObject(hBitmapMem);
    }

    if (!_hdc)
        EndPaint(hWnd, &paint);
}
```

Also i found i have another problem with this.
i move my window in WM_TIMER, i call my __onpaint, problem im having is that it does not redraw it has something todo with the alphaBlend, it keeps what ever was under the window at the time of 1st draw, since it worked before i was using that

Comment: Usually you need `AlphaBlend` when you are drawing over a bitmap image with semi-tranparency . But you don't have any images, you are just writing to `hdc`.  Are you aiming at double-buffering only? or is it something with bitmap images?

Comment: `HDC hDCMem = CreateCompatibleDC(_hdc);` this should be hdc not _hdc

Comment: oh i missed that, im trying to draw a semi transparent rect over my fully transparent window

Comment: *hBitmapMem* is a monochrome bitmap. See the Remarks section of [CreateCompatibleBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183488.aspx): *"When a memory device context is created, it initially has a 1-by-1 monochrome bitmap selected into it. If this memory device context is used in **CreateCompatibleBitmap**, the bitmap that is created is a monochrome bitmap. To create a color bitmap, use the **HDC** that was used to create the memory device context [...]"*

Answer (score 0):

double buffering is to do all your printing and drawing on a temporary bitmap, that should be stored somewhere. the drawings on that bitmap can happen outside of WM_PAINT event (eg: on Adding items or selection change).

then on WM_PAINT event, the only thing you have to do is to project that bitmap to the window via BitBlt function or similar functions.

the way you are using AlphaBlend is wrong. AlphaBlend is used to draw images that have an AlphaChanel over an existing image as an overlay.

Comment: im am using alphaBlend to make my rect transparent, as i dont know anyother ways to do this, is there any way you could show me a example or link me to one?

Comment: @ramafe There's nothing wrong with how you're using AlphaBlend; I don't think it has anything to do with your question on double-buffering though.